Poisson log-likelihood parameter estimation with uncertainty on model rate
I have data $k_n$ that I expect to follow a Poisson distribution $P_{\lambda}(k)=\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}$, and a model for the event rate $\lambda$ that depends both on a vector of unknown parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ and a data vector $\mathbf{S_{k}}$ that was measured with some uncertainty $\boldsymbol{\sigma_{S_k}}$. I'm trying to understand how to correctly propagate the uncertainty on my model into the posteriors on $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ that I'll obtain with a MCMC log-likelihood maximization process.
If my data were normally distributed, then this appears straightforward, as the log-likelihood function for the normal distribution has a variance built in:
$$\ell(\boldsymbol{\theta} | x) = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_n^N \frac{(\hat{\lambda}(k_n)-\lambda_n(\boldsymbol{\theta}))^2}{\text{Var}(\lambda_n(\boldsymbol{\theta}))} + \ln(2\pi \cdot \text{Var}(\lambda_n(\boldsymbol{\theta}))$$
where the maximally likely rate $\hat{\lambda}(k_n)$ is simply $k_n$, following from the mean of the Poisson distribution.
I'm aware that this estimator would be poorly behaved for my use case. However, the log-likelihood function for the mean of a Poisson distribution only depends on the model rate $\lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ and has no clear place to input its expected variance:
$$\ell(\boldsymbol{\theta} | x) = \sum_n^N \ln(\lambda_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})) k_n - \lambda_n(\boldsymbol{\theta}) - \ln(k_n!)$$
Is there some version of the Poisson log-likelihood function that factors in the known variance on the model rate $\lambda$, like the Gaussian estimator? Or perhaps a version of the Gaussian estimator that's better behaved for low $k_n$ (in the same vein as this paper)? Am I using entirely the wrong toolkit for this problem?
On the off chance it's relevant, the exact dependence of $\lambda$ on $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is as follows:
$$\lambda_n(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \sum_i^M \theta_i S_i$$
